# ¿Cómo puedo eliminar el valor de un diccionario que se ha guardado en una variable?

Tags: python, diccionarios

estoy haciendo una lista de compra en python, estoy utilizando diccionarios, en ella debo eliminar un producto y al final imprimir el total de la cuenta. He logrado eliminar el producto pero al imprimir el total me sigue sumando el valor de dicho producto, ¿qué puedo hacer?

Código

```
totpro = {}
total = 0
real = True
productos = {
    "Carne": 18000,
    "Gelatina": 2000,
    "Pan": 2100,
    "Arveja": 1800,
    "Promasa": 2100
}

while real:
    op = int(input("\n""----- Opciones -----\n""1. Agregar un producto\n"
                   "2. Eliminar un producto\n""3. Modificar la compra\n""4. Mostrar la compra\n"
                   "5. Imprimir factura de la compra\n""---> "))
    if op == 1:
        compra = input("Escoga el producto deseado\n" "---> ")
        if compra in productos:
            preg = int(input("Digíte la cantidad del producto\n" "---> "))
            sub = preg * productos[compra]
            total += sub
            totpro[compra] = (preg, sub)
        else:
            print("\n""Lo siento,este producto no está disponible\n""  ")

    if op == 2:
        eli = input("Elija el producto a eliminar\n""---> ")
        if eli in totpro:
            del(totpro[eli])
        else:
            print("\n""Este producto no está en tu carrito\n""  ")

    if op == 5:
        for p in totpro:
            print("-", p, " -----", totpro[p][0], "unidades ---------- Valor:", totpro[p][1])
        print("Precio total\n""--->$", float(total))
        print("¡Gracias por su compra!")
        break
```

Answer (score 1):

Además de la solución de @Azt3kCode que funciona perfectamente, yo recomendaría es muchas veces lo que se hace en carritos, obtener el total al momento.

¿Por qué?

Supongamos que tu haces varios procesos al momento de agregar.

```
if compra in productos:
    preg = int(input("Digíte la cantidad del producto\n" "---> "))
    sub = preg * productos[compra]
    total += sub
    # Varios procesos más.
    # .....
    totpro[compra] = (preg, sub)
```

En este código, si alguno de los `procesos más` falla, se habrá aumentado el total, pero no el ítem en el carrito.

Por eso y para más seguro puedes solo sacar el total al momento.

```
if op == 5:
    total = 0
    for p in totpro:
        print("-", p, " -----", totpro[p][0], "unidades ---------- Valor:", totpro[p][1])
        total += totpro[p][0] * totpro[p][1]
    print("Precio total\n""--->$", float(total))
    print("¡Gracias por su compra!")
    break
```

De esta forma el total siempre estará alineado con lo que tengas en tu carrito.

Comment: Gracias por tu respuesta, la coloqué en la otra parte del código y cuando estaba probandolo no me funcionó, me aparece este error.                           total += total[p][0] * total[p][1]                                                                                 TypeError: 'int' object is not subscriptable

Comment: El problema es que era con `totpro` y no con `total` lo he corregido en la respuesta

Answer (score 0):

Antes de eliminar el producto deseado, deberías restar el subtotal al total:

```
total -= totpro[eli][1]
```

tal que te quedaría de esta manera la opción 2:

```
if op == 2:
        eli = input("Elija el producto a eliminar\n""---> ")
        if eli in totpro:
            total -= totpro[eli][1]
            del(totpro[eli])
        else:
            print("\n""Este producto no está en tu carrito\n""  ")
```

Comment: Hola, gracias por tu respuesta, me sirve bastante bien, sin embargo cuando modifico la cantidad de un producto y luego elimino otro, el valor total me da completamente diferente.

Comment: En ese caso, también deberías aplicar una resta en la opción de Modificación, en la que solo restaras la cantidad de productos deseados por el precio del producto al total.

Comment: Era lo que me faltaba, gracias